# What's a good dark colored web browser for nightime viewing?

Tags: web-browser, dark-theme

What's a good dark colored web browser for nightime viewing?

From the past Stack Exchange posts, the closest solution for Chrome and Firefox is to use F.lux and also download DarkReader extension (which makes Chrome look darker) and also edit some code in the Chrome files to deal with the issue of the white page that opens whenever you open a new tab / go to a new website.

However, I won't resort to changing the code because

- Changing the code doesn't seem to fix it in Chrome 2015 anymore
- Sometimes I will want to revert back to regular mode instead of DarkReader and don't want to deal with hassle of changing the code

So at this point, I'd just like to find a web browser that just by default is dark colored and never has to deal with the white flash of light you get when opening a new Chrome or Firefox tab.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: Do you know about f.lux's darkroom option? It essentially blanks the green and blue channels and inverts the red one, screen-space. Very fast, too.

Answer (score 1):

The best dark time mode in any browser is to use Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/stylish/)). The main site is [userstyles](https://userstyles.org), and as for 'dark', I'd suggest just looking for global themes. There are many display bugs that effect complete overhauls. I'm personally using [Black Web](https://userstyles.org/styles/78507/black-web) and [High Contrast](https://userstyles.org/styles/101643/high-contrast) and every site I go to are working just fine.

As for dark by default, I'm pretty sure only Firefox has this. It's options - content - font and colors - colors - text and background.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked your answer before I posted. Stylish is another great option though. The one feature I don't believe it has is the ability to quickly enable or disable it using a toolbar button, which you can do using Blank Your Monitor.

Comment: sorry for the late reply --- you actually can in stylish. you just have to add the button to a bar. it takes 2 clicks to fully disable all styles, or 2 clicks each to manually disable 1. BYOM is a good basic choice, but after i saw many great userstyles, i switched to stylish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any good browser that is natively dark. The best solution I have found is to use Firefox with the [Blank Your Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/) add-on. It works extremely well and lets you customize the colors of the hyperlinks as well. I use it daily. It also includes a toolbar button/drop-down menu to quickly toggle it on & off. You can then download [New Tab Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/) to set any tabs you open to default to a page of your choosing. If you set it to something like blackle.com then each new tab you open will start dark. Hope this answers your question. There may be some really low budget browser out there you can find that's natively black, but it won't be nearly as secure or supported as Firefox is.